# Printing a whole webview webpage

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm building a webview base app for android and I need a print function.
I tried that:

```
var printMgr = (PrintManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.PrintService);

if (((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt) >= 21)
    printMgr.Print("my page", webview.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter("my page"), null);
else
    printMgr.Print("my page", webview.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(), null);
```

However it only prints the visible part of the page.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember exactly where I used that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want bitmap, Use following class to get one

```
public class Screenshot {

    public static Bitmap get(Context context,WebView view){
        float width=getWindowWidth(context);
        float height=view.getContentHeight() * getDensity(context);
        return capture(view,width,height);
    }
    private static Bitmap capture(View view, float width, float height) {
        if (!view.isDrawingCacheEnabled()) {
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        }
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        int left = view.getLeft();
        int top = view.getTop();
        int status = canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(-left, -top);
        float scale = width / view.getWidth();
        canvas.scale(scale, scale, left, top);
        view.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(status);
        Paint alphaPaint = new Paint();
        alphaPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 1f, height, alphaPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(width - 1f, 0f, width, height, alphaPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width, 1f, alphaPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0f, height - 1f, width, height, alphaPaint);
        canvas.setBitmap(null);
        return bitmap;
    }
    private static int getWindowWidth(Context context) {
        return context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
    private static float getDensity(Context context) {
        return context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }
}
```

If you want to print try replacing

```
    printMgr.Print("my page", webview.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(), null);
```

with

```
printMgr.Print("my page", webview.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(), new PrintAttributes.Builder().build()));
```

this worked for me

Comment: Does it print the whole webView or only visible part?

Answer (score 0):

Just let webview to load completely then call the `createWebPagePrint` function, instead of calling `createWebPagePrint` function immediately.

```
public void createWebPagePrint(WebView webView) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");
        String jobName = "Job_Name";
        PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
        builder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
        builder.setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS);
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, builder.build());
    }
```